# How to install Java 8 on Kali Nethunter

Tags: linux, java, kali-linux, jdk, openjdk

Guys I need to install jdk 8 for my programs to work better, many programs do not support the version higher than Java 8 so I want to install Java 8 to run better, I tried to install via apt-get, but I saw that it was **removed** from the Kali repository because  very **old.** Can anyone help me how to install? When I run the command `uname -m` it shows me that the architecture is aarch64 can someone tell me how to install Java 8 on Nethunter for aarch64?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I managed to solve by adding this line to my **sources.list:**

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

and then I ran this command:

```
apt-update
```

And then this:

```
 apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And finally this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Then just choose Java 8 and that's it, Java is running :)